# Calling STA COM object from WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, com, sta, mta

Is C#'s Runtime Callable Wrapper around a STA remote application type library safe (from the thread model and apartments perspective) to be called from a MTA thread context (.Net WebApi request)?

Should I change the server STA application to MTA or the RCW will handle these mechanisms behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An RCW is a .NET proxy for the COM proxy.  It doesn't matter which apartment you're on in your .NET application, the RCW will handle marshaling for you.

And since the object is remote, you don't need to worry if apartments are compatible, the communication crosses processes.  If you'd be using a native language and environment, such as C++, you'd only have to worry not to share the COM proxy across apartments, or in other words, to properly marshal proxy references in each apartment.

If the object was in-process, you'd gain performance for sharing the same apartment, but between processes, marshaling and thread scheduling delays will be the greatest overhead.

However, you should consider what apartment other application uses.  Applications that use an STA will be single-threaded, so this will be a bottleneck for your ASP.NET application.  If it uses an MTA, perhaps not, if it doesn't synchronize all calls or if the critical sections are fast.

For applications, you usually can't control the used apartment.  How would you change its apartment?  Is this a COM+ component?  Is this your code?  Is it ready for the apartment switch?

Comment: Basically I would change to free-threaded and apply some locking in critical regions of the code. But this IPC mechanism is rarely used compared to other features in the application so the performance would not be a problem. I think i'll leave as it is.

Comment: I am having problem in the RCW's class constructor, it raises type_e_cantloadlibrary intermittently, closing the out-of-proc server solves, but this is not a quality solution for production environment. Hence the question.

Comment: I believe you're talking about an in-process server (DLL) instead of an out-of-process server (EXE, DLL using surrogate).  Changing the registered apartment for an in-process server easily done in the registry, but the server must support that type of apartment.  Changing the apartment used by an out-of-process server (that doesn't use a surrogate) usually means changing the code or using some application-specific setting.

Comment: As for TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY, the type library might not be properly registered, or this is an in-process server with a different bitness than the hosting process.  Try setting the "Enable 32-Bit Applications" setting to "True" for the application pool.  Also, if the server is an Office object, this is an officially unsupported scenario.

Comment: The only in-process is the interop.xxxx.dll generated by the tlbimp.exe. My  automated object is out-of-process (i.e spawns another process) i'm sure about that. Could you elaborate on the officially unsupported scenario of Office? maybe my automated object is falling into the same issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, and your time I really appreciate your help. :-)

Comment: is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10615232/2087187) possibly related?

Comment: No, unless you're using a **library** instead of an **application**.  Can you provide the component's registration details, such as the CLSID entry and all values within its subkeys such as InprocServer32, LocalServer, etc?  As for the unsupported scenario, here it is: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757).

Comment: I think i'll close this question as solved, and ask a new specifically about the exception, what do you think? I didn't accepted yet because I was waiting for more upvotes. Everything i've read confirms what you've said, but I was waiting just to make sure that this is well known.

Comment: I believe that if an answer satisfies the question from the op's point of view (yours, in this case), it should be accepted.  Usually, practical programming questions are easier to validate and accept, compared to more abstract questions and/or answers.  The time the op decides to give is mostly if they believe others might step in with more satisfactory answers, or comments to already good enough answers.  You don't have to wait, you should go ahead and post a new question anyway, you can leave accepting an answer on this one for later.

Comment: The type library issue was due to the fact I was connect to a RDP server with multiple/different users, the external application got registered every time for a different user, when they were debugging the web application. This will probably not happen in prod so I will just note down this problem and take the risk... I'l leave as it is.